# Tkinter label not updating like it should be

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The program I'm working on was working correctly earlier today.  The only change I had made was trying and finally getting the program set up so it would zoom in on the center of the canvas not on the left edge of the canvas.  In the process of getting it to do that I started noticing something going wrong otherwise with the program.  Definitely behaving very weirdly.  The longitude label in the lower left is updating correctly when the longitude was between 0 and -99.999999 otherwise if it was -100 or less it was very slow to update the longitude.  I decided to try to narrow down the problem and inserted print(px) into the program and saw that it was working fine it was just the label that wasn't updating.  After getting several other things working quite nicely I came back and still haven't been able to figure it out.  The code below is from the program and does exactly what I'm seeing with the full program.  When you go further west/left than -100 the label doesn't update timely like it does further east.  The Latitude label updates fine anywhere on the screen, admittedly it goes over 100 or under -100.  How do I correct this and keep everything else working correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="black", width=714, height=714)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.longitudecenter = -95.767018
        self.latitudecenter = 38.956862
        self.p = 58.5
        global v
        global w
        s = Frame(self, width=150, height=20)
        s.pack_propagate(0)
        s.place(x=0,y=695)
        v = Label(s, fg='black',anchor='w')
        v.pack()
        t = Frame(self, width=150, height=20)
        t.pack_propagate(0)
        t.place(x=150,y=695)
        w = Label(t, fg='black',anchor='w')
        w.pack()

        parent.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

    def on_motion(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete("sx")
        self.startx, self.starty = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x),self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        px = -(round((-self.longitudecenter + (self.p/2))- (self.startx * (self.p/714)),5))
        py = round((self.latitudecenter + (self.p/2))-(self.starty * (self.p /714)),5)
        print(px)
        if len(str(px)) == 9:
            v.config(text = "Longitude: " + str(px))
        if len(str(px)) == 8:
            v.config(text = "Longitude: " + str(px) + '0')
        if len(str(px)) == 7:
            v.config(text = "Longitude: " + str(px) + '00')
        if len(str(px)) == 6:
            v.config(text = "Longitude: " + str(px) + '000')
        if len(str(px)) == 5:
            v.config(text = "Longitude: " + str(px) + '0000')
        if len(str(py)) == 9:
            w.config(text = "Latitude: " + str(py))
        if len(str(py)) == 8:
            w.config(text = "Latitude: " + str(py) + '0')
        if len(str(py)) == 7:
            w.config(text = "Latitude: " + str(py) + '00')
        if len(str(py)) == 6:
            w.config(text = "Latitude: " + str(py) + '000')
        if len(str(py)) == 5:
            w.config(text = "Latitude: " + str(py) + '0000')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `len(str(px))` is sometimes 10. When that happens, you aren't updating the widget. This was easily determined with a simple print statement.

Comment: I never changed anything in regards to that and never had the problem until this morning.  Strange but that does eliminate the problem.  It may have been when I changed from a full longitude to a decimal longitude that it caused the formula answer to spew up a larger number that caused the hiccup to occur.  Weird.  I sure can't come up with any other reasoning for it to change like that.